# Tamir SharpSSH not able to connect again. error "SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many users for this IP"

Tags: c#, sharpssh

I am facing strange issue in Tamir SharpSSH while connecting it. first time when I connect SFTP using below code, it connect successfully. but when this method calls again it breaks into this error : **SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many users for this IP**

```
public bool getDir(string directory){
     Sftp s = new Sftp(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPUrl"], username, password);
s.Connect();
s.Mkdir(directory);
s.Close();

}
```

This issue happens only at my production environment not from my localhost.
please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information, but it looks to me like the SFTP server is preventing you from connecting too often. Maybe you can keep the `Sftp` object around instead of creating/closing it every time?